# StringGetPos in AHK always gives an OutputVar = -1

Tags: user-interface, macros, autohotkey

So, I copy to clipboard this text and i want to know the location of the word 'book' so i wrote this code:

```
StringCaseSense, on  
StringGetPos, OutputVar, %clipboard%, book  
msgbox, %OutputVar%
```

But it always returns the value '-1' which means that it didn't find 'book' in clipboard but IT IS INSIDE THE TEXt I'VE COPIED. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The input variable IS a variable, so you don't need the `%`'s to signify that you don't want the literal.  My answer follows:

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
StringCaseSense, on  
StringGetPos, OutputVar, Clipboard, book  
msgbox, %OutputVar%
```

Hth,